# Simulating UISegmentedControl with 2 UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to have two custom buttons to simulate how a UISegmentedControl behaves (switch button text color and image)

Here is what I have so far:

```
    - (IBAction)byDateTapped:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIColor *darkColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:52/255 green:91/255 blue:120/255 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *lightColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:158/255 green:200/255 blue:217/255 alpha:1.0];

    self.byDateView.hidden = NO;
    [self.byDateButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioOn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.byDateButton setTitleColor:darkColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.byDateButton setTitleColor:darkColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    self.byCategoryView.hidden = YES;
    [self.byCategoryButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioOff"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.byCategoryButton setTitleColor:lightColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.byCategoryButton setTitleColor:lightColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

}

- (IBAction)byCategoryTapped:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIColor *darkColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:52/255 green:91/255 blue:120/255 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *lightColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:158/255 green:200/255 blue:217/255 alpha:1.0];

    self.byDateView.hidden = YES;
    [self.byDateButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioOff"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.byDateButton setTitleColor:lightColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.byDateButton setTitleColor:lightColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    self.byCategoryView.hidden = NO;
    [self.byCategoryButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioOn"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.byCategoryButton setTitleColor:darkColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.byCategoryButton setTitleColor:darkColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

}
```

The only thing that I can't seem to get to work is changing the button text color. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your IBAction methods should be as simple as

`- (IBAction)byDateTapped:(UIButton *)sender {`

```
[self.byDateButton setSelected:YES];
[self.byCategoryButton setSelected:NO];

}
```

`- (IBAction)byCategoryTapped:(UIButton *)sender {`

```
[self.byDateButton setSelected:NO];
[self.byCategoryButton setSelected:YES];

}
```

You should do all the setup for all the states on your initialisation code (`viewDidLoad`).

Instead of `UIControlStateHighlighted`, you should use `UIControlStateSelected` instead. FYI, You can also do the same thing for background image.

For example:

```
[_byDateButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_byDateButton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[_byCategoryButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_byCategoryButton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```